# How to retrieve the HTTP code using postman from a Json slim response?

Tags: php, json, postman, slim, postman-collection-runner

I'm currently developing a REST API with the Slim framework.
To test my API I'm using postman but I can't retrieve the status code sent by the slim method:

```
$response->withJson($data, $status, $encodingOptions)

$slimApp->post('/v1/users', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    echo $response->withJson(['data' => 'something'], 400);
});
```

I set the status code to '400' but postman keep saying it's a '200' status.

The header sent by slim is :

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>   Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8

The fact is that, I can manually verify the code status with the header, but I would like to verify it through the collection runner of postman.

Do you have any idea about this postman behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relating to [this issue](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1827#issuecomment-202803809) in the slim github repository you have to return the response, instead of echoing it:

```
$slimApp->post('/v1/users', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $response->withJson(['data' => 'something'], 400);
});
```